# What is the basis for saying that the Catholic Church is the largest charitable organization in the world?

Tags: catholicism, charity

I would prefer actual numbers comparing it to other organizations.

In addition, bonus points if you can demonstrate that the catholic church effectively does the most good or essentially highly efficient with how they spend their money.  It is quite irrelevant if someone receives lots of donations but does not spend the money well.  None of the links in the following question seemed to work or seemed highly speculative to me (the economist answer).

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/approximate-amount-of-money-per-year-the-catholic-church-spends-for-charity) is related.  [This is](https://web.archive.org/web/20081227021108/http://www.catholicscomehome.org/epic/Epic_%20proof.pdf) is a source I found online; I'm not sure what to think of it though.

Comment: That's going to be REALLY difficult. There's often no central agency to which all the local offices of (e.g.) Catholic Charities report all their expenses, let alone a central agency to which all Catholic charitable services report.

Comment: @MattGutting then can you please get organizations to stop telling people this.  Just kidding ;)  I will add what little rep I have as bounty unless this gets closed for some reason.

Comment: Hi @William To be really useful, I suggest this question could do with some tailoring.  For example, when you say 'largest' do you mean the largest organisation that is in part involved in charity, or do you mean the organisation that expends the most money and/or manpower in charitable service, or do you just mean 'the most successful'? Do you regard missionary work as charity, or is charity some work that benefits the poor? Without  guidance to what you mean, answers can cherrypick definitions such as these to prove that any number of organisations are  the largest charitable organisations.

Comment: @DickHarfield I'm not sure what organizations are referring to when they say this.  Here is one possible source of where I have found such information although it is just facebook https://www.facebook.com/notes/michael-sanchez/the-catholic-church-is-the-largest-charitable-organization-in-the-world/399364450111086/  I have heard this from Catholics before that is all.  I can't really narrow down what the quote is referring to.

Comment: Is this perhaps better for Skeptics SE?

Comment: @Joshua I would agree accept for the fact there is almost duplicate question posted on this site.

Comment: @William No, That one is asking "How much?" a simple, objective question about the church and charity. This one is asking "Is it true?" That is a skeptics question.

Comment: [The Catholic Church is the LARGEST charitable organization in the world.](https://www.facebook.com/notes/michael-sanchez/the-catholic-church-is-the-largest-charitable-organization-in-the-world/399364450111086/)

Comment: @KenGraham I'm confused are you trying to say that the post I and you both linked is a valid source?

Comment: @William, that Facebook source hardly qualifies as authoritative, as it gives no stats to back it up.

Comment: On second thoughts is this even on topic here?

Comment: @Pam skeptics maybe.  The question was so close to the other linked question is the only reason why I asked it.

Comment: I suspect it would be on topic at Skeptics.SE, but that doesn't mean it is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.SE -- they are all about addressing such claims.

Comment: @Dan I would agree except for this question http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/approximate-amount-of-money-per-year-the-catholic-church-spends-for-charity

Answer (score 1):

Three factors enter in to answering this question.
Number 1 ). is the Catholic Church a charitable organization?

> A charitable organization is a type of non-profit organization (NPO). It differs from other types of NPOs in that it centers on philanthropic goals as well as social well-being (e.g. charitable, educational, religious, or other activities serving the public interest or common good).

According to that definition yes the Catholic Church is a charitable organization.

Number 2 ) how many people make up the Catholic Church?

> There are an estimated 1.2 billion Roman Catholics in the world, according to Vatican figures. More than 40% of the world's Catholics live in Latin America - but Africa has seen the biggest growth in Catholic congregations in recent years.

That means the charitable organization known as the Catholic Church is 1.2 billion people strong.

Number 3). Is there any other charitable organization that can claim more than 1.2 billion people as members?

No there is not.

Therefore the Catholic Church is in fact the largest charitable organization on earth.

Comment: Looking at the wording of the question, it seems clear that "largest" was not intended in terms of membership, but in terms of money spent on charitable activity, or something similar.

Comment: OP appeared not to know what "largest charity" meant, and this is a very likely meaning.